# Evaluating the Complex line Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

During these days, I am trying to learn myself about complex line integral and I stumble upon a question:
Evaluate
$$I_j=\int_{\gamma_j}xdz$$ from j=1 to 7 and x denotes the real part of the complex z.
I solved for j=1,2,3,4 but I am struck at
1)${\gamma_5}$ is the line from 0 to 2i and then 2i to 4+2i
2)${\gamma_6}$ is the line segment from 0 to 1, 1 to 1+i and then from 1+i to 0.
3)${\gamma_7}$ is given ${\gamma_7}$(t)= t+i${t^2}$ on [0,1].
Could anyone provide me some hints to solve this?

Comment: In each example, you need to first parametrize the line integral, possibly using a piecewise function. For example $\gamma_5(t)$ is equal to $2it$ for $t\in[0,1]$ and then $\gamma_5(t)=2it+(1-t)(4+2i)$ for  $t\in[0,1]$, and you can break the overall line integral into two pieces. After that, pay attention to the real part of $\gamma$.

Comment: @AlexR. since 2it doesn't have a real part ,the integral would be zero and also I have a silly doubt why we took (1-t)?

Comment: For the first piece, yes, the integral is 0 since $x=0$. For the second piece, I'm just using the well known parametrization of a line between two points $a=(a_1,a_2),b=(b_1,b_2)$: $ \gamma(t)=ta+(1-t)b$. At $t=0$, it's just $a$ and $t=1$ it's $b$, otherwise being all points in-between. If this isn't familiar, it will make your life easier to review vectors and vector functions (sections 12,13 of Stewart's Calculus book for example).

Comment: @AlexR.Thanks for the help